# Can't get value from getEntry in Contentful

Tags: node.js, typescript, contentful

I want to get an entry from contentful using contentful v10 Node.js 18, but I can't access to value in getEntry().

```
interface Example {
  contentTypeId: 'item'
  fields:{
   title: EntryFeildTypes.Text
   rate: EntryFeildTypes.Number
  }
}

interface Global {
 contentTypeId: 'product'
  fields:{
    title: EntryFeildTypes.Text
    point: EntryFeildTypes.EntryLink<Example>;
  }
}
const client = Contentful.createClient({...})
const data = await contentful.getEntry<Global>('product')
```

Problem I can't access to rate by doing (data.fields.point.).

Answer (score 0):

The `getEntry` function takes an entry ID and will return that single entry. If you want to fetch all the entries of the type `product`, you will have to use the `getEntry` function. Below is an example:

```js
client.getEntries({ content_type: 'product' }).then(e => console.log(e)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

You can learn more about the SDK here: https://contentful.github.io/contentful.js/contentful/10.1.3/interfaces/ContentfulClientApi.html#getEntry

Hope this helps!